# AngularJS: How to implement global error handler and show errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

for my web page I have several angular apps. For those apps I want to create a global error handler which tracks errors with codes 500, 401 and so on and displays them as alerts.

Here is what I have so far:

I've created a global error handler module which I then inject in my apps

```
angular.module('globalErrorHandlerModule', [])
    .factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', function ($rootScope, $q) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if(rejection.status == 500){
                    // show error
                }

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    });

angular.module('myApp', ['globalErrorHandlerModule'])
```

Now what I'm struggling with is actually displaying the error in an alert. What's the best way to do this? I've tried creating a separate error app and injecting the error module and share a data factory in between, but the data never gets updated in the app. Something like this:

```
angular.module('globalErrorHandlerModule', [])
    .factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', 'Data', function ($rootScope, $q, Data) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if(rejection.status == 500){
                    // set error
                    Data.error.message = '500 error';
                }

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }])
    .factory('Data', function () {
        var _error = {
            message: "init"
        };
        return {
            error: _error
        };
    })
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    });

angular.module('globalErrorHandlerApp', ['globalErrorHandlerModule'])
    .controller('GlobalErrorCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
        $scope.test = Data.error.message;
    });
```

And then displaying the error as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="GlobalErrorCtrl">
         Error {{test}}    
</div>
```

But as mentioned I only see my initial value, and no updates to the error message. I've also tried broadcasting but that didn't work either. I'm sure there's a better way to implement something like this, I just haven't found it yet. Thanks for any tips pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
angular.module('globalErrorHandlerApp', ['globalErrorHandlerModule'])
.controller('GlobalErrorCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
    $scope.test = Data.error;
});
```

its a better idea watch an object than a string.
let me know if help you

```
<div ng-controller="GlobalErrorCtrl">
     Error <span> {{test.message}}   </span>  
</div>
```